# wp-plugin options multi-select not saving

Tags: php, wordpress

I have multi select in options tab in a custom wordpress plugin that I made. The multi-select stopped saving recently, when I select some options click save, it all becomes unselected. When I change it to a single select it works to save one option.

```
    $this->form_fields = apply_filters( $this->option_name . '_settings_fields', array(
            array(
            'name'      => __( 'Search in (hold the CTRL to select multiple)', 'refyn' ),
            'class'     => 'refyn_seach_in',
            'id'        => 'refyn_seach_in',
            'type'      => 'multiselect',
            'default'   => 'post',
            'options'   => $search_in,
            'free_version'      => true,
        ),
```

multi select in options tab wp-plugin:

[image: screenshot]

the word "multiselect" is actuated as

```
<?php if ( $value['type'] == 'multiselect' ) echo 'multiple="multiple"'; ?>
```

I have tried reinstalling the plugin on other sites to no avail.
Would anyone have any idea why is it stopped working?
thanks